# How to convert time data formatted in Excel from 12:02:23 AM/0:02:23 into decimals? Like 2.23

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been struggling with transforming the avgtalkduration column into decimals before exporting it into power BI. For example, data displayed as 12:02:23 AM or 0:02:23 should be translated into 2.23 (For easy reading). Which formula should I implemented or in which way I should achieved the result I wanted?

This is the image showing the excel sheet that I encountered issue:
[image]

Thank you in advanced.

I've tried a bunched of formulas provided by chatGPT like =TIMEVALUE(I2)/3600 + MINUTE(I2)/60 + SECOND(I2)/3600 (This formula shows #VALUE! error)

The second formula I've tried was =HOUR(I2) + MINUTE(I2)/60 + SECOND(I2)/3600
(This formula has no error but displayed as 0.04 in decimals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

If you only want to make a timestamp look as "minutes:seconds", open Format Cells dialog, go to Custom format (last line in the list) and choose format `mm:ss`. It will make `00:02:23` look as `2:23` while keeping the timestamp intact.

If you want to extract minutes and seconds from timestamp and combine them in a string the way you want it, then (assuming your timestamp in cell `A1`)

`=MINUTE(A1)&":"&SECOND(A1)`

Keep in mind that you will not be able to sum or subtract results of this formula - it is not a value, it is a string.

Note: Both methods assume that your avgtalkduration contains values! Based on your screenshot, it appears they are values. However, if you got there strings instead, you need to convert them to values.

Raw timestamp in Excel is a decimal fraction. If you are not certain, change format of any timestamp to General. If the timestamp does not become a fraction, its a string. Use `TIMEVALUE()` to convert your timestamps to values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! That really helps clarify my doubts a lot.

Comment: @PataminAurluecha you are most welcome. Make sure to click the checkmark if you choose this method as answer. This will add it to database of verified solutions and let others with the same problem find it in future.